# Is there an autonimus realtime clock wilth month loss less than 10milliseconds?

Tags: iot, stm32, clock, zigbee, real-time-clock

Looking for a realtime clock for IoT project. Need a millisecond resolution for my app protocol and its loss is critical. So I wonder if there is an  autonimus realtime clock (with a battery) that will loose less than 10ms per month and work for a year?

Answer (score 3):

The drift parameters you're asking for here -- 10 ms / 30 days -- imply <4 ppb accuracy. This will be a very difficult target to hit. A typical quartz timing crystal of the type used by most RTCs will drift by 50 - 100+ **ppm** (50,000 - 100,000 ppb) just based on temperature fluctuations.

Most of the higher-quality timing options (TCXO, OCXO, etc) will not be usable within your power budget -- a typical OCXO may require as much as 1W of (continuous) power to run its heater. About the only viable option I can think of would be a GPS timing receiver, which can synchronize a low-quality local oscillator to the GPS time, which is highly accurate.

Ultimately, though, I suspect your best option will be to modify your protocol to loosen or remove these timing requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Sync it with the precise clock source like GPS for example.

You can also use tiny atomic clock https://physicsworld.com/a/atomic-clock-is-smallest-on-the-market/

or in Europe DCF77 receiver.

Comment: The "tiny atomic clock" you're referring to [costs over $5,000](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microsemi-corporation/090-02984-001/090-02984-001-ND/6805273). This is probably outside the OP's price range.